# NextJS 13 with Sanity - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

Tags: next.js, sanity

I need help with this one:

```
Call Stack
options.factory
file:///C:/Users/tirfa/Projects/nluz-blog/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (722:31)
__webpack_require__
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
file:///C:/Users/tirfa/Projects/nluz-blog/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (377:21)
eval
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react\cjs\react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js (17:12)
eval
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react\cjs\react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js (1328:3)
./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react/cjs/react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js
file:///C:/Users/tirfa/Projects/nluz-blog/.next/static/chunks/app/studio/[[...index]]/page.js (5098:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (722:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/tirfa/Projects/nluz-blog/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (377:21)
eval
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react\jsx-dev-runtime.js (6:2)
./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react/jsx-dev-runtime.js
file:///C:/Users/tirfa/Projects/nluz-blog/.next/static/chunks/app/studio/[[...index]]/page.js (5120:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (722:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/tirfa/Projects/nluz-blog/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (377:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///./app/studio/[[...index]]/page.tsx (5:79)
./app/studio/[[...index]]/page.tsx
file:///C:/Users/tirfa/Projects/nluz-blog/.next/static/chunks/app/studio/[[...index]]/page.js (5001:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (722:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/tirfa/Projects/nluz-blog/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (377:21)
__webpack_require__
node_modules\next\dist\client\app-index.js (26:16)
eval
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\client.js (106:0)
```

I expected the studio. But this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Install the following package, the problem may be solved

`npm i webpack`

Comment: It didn't help, it still occurs.

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error today and realised I had updated to the latest version of next. This appears to be an error in next version 13.0.7.

I fixed this error by downgrading back to 13.0.6

```
npm i next@13.0.6
```